# How to generate Map<String, ...> with Swagger Codegen?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm working on an API where we define the API definition in the swagger.yaml file. The API which I am working on returns an output object which contains a map.

Output Object : OutputClass

```java
public class OutputClass {
   private Map<String, MapValue> map;
   
}
```

Right now, I used:

```yaml
 OutputClass:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      $ref: '#/definitions/MapValue'
```

But Swagger Codegen generates the following Java code:

```java
public class OutputClass extends HashMap<String, MapValue> implements Serializable { 
}
```

Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

Your map definition is correct. There's an open issue with Swagger Codegen about the way it translates OpenAPI maps to Java code: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5187